# How to send Multipart from android to php server?

Tags: php, mysql, rest

Im working on backend of one project where from android app user will upload audio with multipart form data .
Now as i am working on backend i create rest api for upload audio to server.
and i test my code on POSTMAN tool . postman tool gives me perfect answer.
it uploads audio xyz.3gp on server.

But from app it wont be able to send audio to server. and when i create log for this then i come to know that

> if i send audio from POSTMAN i get  xyz.3gp and it uploads on server.
>   if i send audio from app i get xyz. and it wont be upload on server.

Comment: it wont be able to get extension from app

Comment: maybe your apache server couldn't just handle large file(s)

Comment: so wts the solution for this bro

Comment: you're running that on local?

Comment: nop bro. its live.

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"], "audioupload/".$uid."/".$_SESSION["uid"] ."/". $audio_name))  used this for move file on server. it works fine on postman but not working with app

Comment: screen shot your postman